# What is a (spatial) frame of reference in quantum mechanics?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, reference-frames, coordinate-systems

For me this question becomes really apparent when we make a transformation e.g. in a H-atom from the proton frame of reference to the electron frame of reference. The whole point of QM is that the electron cannot be treated as a dot somewhere in space but that it has an associated wavefunction and only acquires a certain position when I make an appropriate measurement. So how can I transform to the electron frame of reference making the origin to be the position of the electron if I don't know it?

In a wider sense how can I define a coordinate system in quantum mechanics? The usual "take a corner of the lab as the origin and the edges of the walls as axes" surely doesn't work because these all consist of particles that don't have well-defined positions.

Comment: You can arbitrary define the origin. The approach of taking the corner of the lab as origin works pretty well. If you are unsatisfied with the particles of the wall, you can just define the origin to be the average position of the wavefunction of your electron.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The electron doesn't have a position so it makes no sense to talk about a frame with the origin at the position of the electron.

You can choose a frame in which the expectation value of the electron momentum is zero i.e. a frame in which the electron is on average stationary. Then shift the origin of this frame to make the expectation value of the electron position is zero. That would be a plausible candidate for the frame of the electron. This would of course coincide with the frame of the proton.

Comment: Your starting statement is not fully compatible with non-relativistic QM. Actually, it is possible to assign a position to an electron.  HUP only makes it impossible to think about a reference frame with its origin *always coinciding with the position of the electron*. However, this is not necessary. It is enough to be able to determine with arbitrary precision the position of electron and proton at the same time (conceptually possible), then the difference of position vectors (a well-defined object) is all we need in the formalism (for example in the Schrödinger equation).

Comment: @GiorgioP the point I'm making is that there are no position eigenstates because they are not physical states.

Comment: If a self-adjoint operator has a continuous spectrum, there is no eigenvalue. However, there is a projection-valued measure used to express the spectral theorem, i.e. to represent the possible outcomes of measurements. The result for the position operator (or for the momentum operator) is that any finite interval of real numbers, that can be arbitrarily small. Therefore, at least in the sense of a limit, there is no lower bound to the precision of a measurement position. This is the precise meaning of the sentence that a quantum particle may have a well-defined position ...(continue)

Comment: ...(at the time the measurement is performed). But this is all we need to assign an operative meaning to the position label in any QM formula.

Comment: I think I disagree with this statement. It's only true for "classical frames" If your frame of reference itself is a probabilistic object [ex: its origin is given by a distribution] then you can certainly attach a frame to an electron, see my answer here: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/671523/how-are-frames-of-references-compatible-with-quantum-mechanics?noredirect=1&lq=1